# Access 2013 ComboBox value based on other ComboBox with Junction Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

Good day. This is a follow-up to a previous question. I have a form with 2 comboboxes where the 2nd one depends on the value in the 1st one. I have the code to show the drop down list in the 2nd combobox but I am unable to select anything but the first entry.
Table 1: name - Supply_Sources, fields - Source_ID(pk), SupplySourceName

Table 2: name - Warehouse_Locations, fields - WLocation_ID(pk), Location_Name

Table 3 (junction): name - SupplySource_WarehouseLocation, fields - Supply_Source_ID(pk), Location_In_ID(pk)

On my form 'frmInventoryReceivedInput' I have cboSupplySource and cboWLocation. I populate cboSupplySource with

```
    SELECT [Supply_Sources].[Source_ID], [Supply_Sources].[SupplySourceName] 
    FROM Supply_Sources;
```

The SQL for cboWLocation is:

```
    SELECT SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID,
    Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name FROM Warehouse_Locations 
    INNER JOIN (Supply_Sources INNER JOIN SupplySource_WarehouseLocation
     ON Supply_Sources.Source_ID = SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID) 
    ON Warehouse_Locations.WLocation_ID =  SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID 
    WHERE ((( SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID)=
    [forms]![frmInventoryReceivedInput]![cboSupplySource]));
```

There are 3 options for me in the cboWLocation drop down list (based on cboSupplySource).  However, it doesn't matter which one I choose, it defaults to the first one.  What do I need to do to be able to choose the other options?

Comment: ON Supply_Sources.Source_ID = SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID?

Comment: are you updating cboWLocation when the value of cboSupplySource changes?  Not sure what the problem is, the 2nd cbo doesn't update or doesn't allow you to select the 2nd item in the list?

Comment: That was a typo - there is a '=' in the coding.  I have a requery attached to cboSupplySource to update cboWLocation when there is a change. Yes, the 2nd cbo doesn't allow choosing anything but the first item in the list.

Comment: is the 2nd cbo doing anything else after it's selected, or does anything else effect the 2nd cbo?  does the 2nd cbo update ok when you change the 1st one?  Is the 2nd cbo dropping down so you can confirm it's updating the way you expect?

Comment: both cbo's are read by vba code (there's another text box on the form that is dealt with in vba depending on the combination of the cbo's - there is no link or code to doing anything with the cbo's).  Nothing else affects either cbo and they have no affect on anything else.  2nd cbo updates ok after the requery and drops down correctly.

Comment: so it's just after the 2nd cbo drops down and you try to click on the 2nd or later item, that it reloads the cbo?  try putting a stop at your code loading the 2nd cbo and see if it's being called when you don't want it to.

Comment: when I click on the drop down indicator I can move to the 2nd and 3rd items.  However, when I click on either one, the first item shows in the box - is that a 'reload'?.  When I tab out of cbo1 to cbo2, cbo2 is blank waiting for my selection in the drop down list.  There is no default setting in my cbo2 properties.  The vba code is called from a command button at the bottom of the form.  The problem is local to the form/comboboxes.  For cbo2: Column Count is 2. Widths are 0;1. Bound Column is 1. Limit to List is Yes. There are no Events on cbo2.

Comment: try putting a breakpoint on your VBA code's requery call.  It might be called from the wrong event.

Comment: the requery is an embedded macro in cbo1, After Update, with control name cbo2.   Is this not what generates the correct drop down list in cbo2?  In other words, it should have nothing to do with the vba code, I believe.  This all happens on the form, before going into the code.

Comment: yeah, there's something else going on, and from the information you've provided, I can't tell what.  The code is related to the form, however.  They're not two different things.

Comment: Ok. I will try another form with 2 cbo's that doesn't involve a many-to-many relationship and see if that works.  There are a lot of examples of that coding but nothing I can find when its a m-m. Any other suggestions of what should be in the vba code, or the form or combobox properties, that I may have overlooked?  Thanks so much for your time til now.

Comment: Just to let you know I created a new form with 2 cbo's with a simple one-to-many relationship and I was able to choose any item in cbo2's drop down list.  I tried the same with the m-m and still have the same original problem i.e. only allows item 1 even when I choose item 2 or 3 in the drop down list.  In this case there is no VBA code at all - just SQL in the form.  So, there is something in the SQL that my access doesn't like. Frustrating!

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to matter, though.  It's like it expects it to be an editable list, which it isn't.  Do you have properties set so the cbo entries are limited to the list, they can't add new ones?  Check the 'allow value list edits' property and make sure it's NO, this is not an editable recordset.  You can also check the 'locked' property and make sure it's FALSE.

Comment: the settings were as you've indicated - no difference (errrr!!!) (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I recreated it and it works OK, the only thing I did differently was create a query with the SQL:

```
    SELECT 
SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID, Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name
    FROM 
Warehouse_Locations INNER JOIN 
(Supply_Sources INNER JOIN 
SupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON 
Supply_Sources.Source_ID = SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID) ON 
Warehouse_Locations.WLocation_ID = SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID
    WHERE 
(((SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID)=
[forms]![frmInventoryReceivedInput]![cboSupplySource]));
```

so I could check that part separately from the UI.

For cboWLocation, I have `column widths` 0";1", `rowSource` qry_cbo2, and `bound column` 2.  Try changing your bound column from 1 to 2 and see if that helps.

-Beth

Comment: Good day, Beth.  I plugged in your qry_cbo2 and I did change the bound column to 2. I am as expected able to choose a different item from cbo2 drop down list, with the list dependent on cbo1.  I added the following code: Private Sub cboWLocation_AfterUpdate()
        MsgBox "You selected " & Me.cboSupplySource.Column(1) & "  value in Placed where is " & Me.cboWLocation.Column(1)
End Sub

Comment: ... the rest of my comment:  cboWLocation returns (as text) the location that I selected.  I want to get the ID(pk) # from column 1.  When I use .column(0) it returns the ID(pk) # of cbo1, regardless of cbo2. Any other thoughts?

Comment: yes, use the .value property of the cbo, that will return the bound column.  The .text value should return the entry in the text box.

Comment: Ok, I'm missing something.  Column 2 is bound to cbo2 (i.e. cboWLocation).   If I choose cbo2 = 'garbage', which is item 2 in the drop down list for cbo2 and has a unique autonum of 35 (in column 1),  I get the following:  msgbox cbo2 returns "garbage"; msgbox cbo2.value returns "garbage"; msgbox cbo2.text returns "error 2185 You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus."  Have I misunderstood your last suggestion?  I want to get msgbox cbo2  to return '35' (for 'garbage') i.e. the number from column 1. Or should I just do a DLookup for that number?

Comment: sorry, try using the itemdata(cbo.listindex) property, like [here](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access.formscoding/how-to-get-the-value-at-t/16662)

Comment: Hello, I really do appreciate all your efforts.  However, it is still not returning what I want.  I have added the following and did get the result I was looking for: MsgBox DLookup("[WLocation_ID]", "Warehouse_Locations", "[Location_Name] = '" & Me.cboWLocation & "'").